# Delphi XE7 Abstract Error on StyleLookup with Effect (FireMonkey)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

For starters, I'm writing an application for a customer that relies heavily on custom styles. These styles are composed of several sub controls and visual effects (TBlurEffect, TShadowEffect, etc...)

On my dev machine these effects and styles render correctly with no errors (Windows Server 2012), the same goes for another test machine running windows 7. When attempting to run on one of the client's servers, I receive an Abstract error when the style is applied. I created a test app with 4 different styles included (3 of which have effects and 1 which is just a TRectangle). The 3 effect styles all give the same Abstract error, but the simple rectangle style does not (leading me to believe this is the culprit).

I verified the clients machine is compliant to the specs, but I still feel something is off:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/FireMonkey_Platform_Prerequisites

Ultimately, I would like these effects to work, but if there is something off with the customers system compared to the Firemonkey requirements I would like to see if there is some kind of directive or global variable that I could use to check with, and disable the effects at runtime. If anyone could help that would be appreciated.

Customers dxdiag results:
------------------ System Information
------------------ Time of this report: 3/10/2015, 10:28:20
      Machine name: ##REMOVED##   Operating System: Windows Server 2003, Enterprise Edition (5.2, Build 3790) Service Pack 2 (3790.srv03_sp2_qfe.130703-1535)
          Language: English (Regional Setting: English) System Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
      System Model: PowerEdge 1950
              BIOS: Phoenix ROM BIOS PLUS Version 1.10 2.7.0
         Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5310  @ 1.60GHz (8 CPUs), ~1.6GHz
            Memory: 8186MB RAM
         Page File: 3175MB used, 6861MB available
       Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS    DirectX Version: DirectX 9.0c (4.09.0000.0904) DX Setup Parameters: Not found
    DxDiag Version: 5.03.3790.3959 32bit Unicode

My test Project:

```
program Project1;   
uses
  System.StartUpCopy,
  FMX.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

My test Unit:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.ListBox,FMX.NumberBox,FMX.TabControl;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StyleBook1: TStyleBook;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Self.StyleBook:=StyleBook1;
  ComboBox1.Items.Clear;
  for I := 0 to StyleBook1.Style.ChildrenCount-1 do
  Begin
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(StyleBook1.Style.Children[i].StyleName);
  End;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ComboBox1.ItemIndex>-1 then
    Panel1.StyleLookup:=ComboBox1.Selected.Text;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.StyleBook:=Nil;
  Panel1.StyleLookup:='';
  ComboBox1.Items.Clear;
end;

end.
```

My Form:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object StyleBook1: TStyleBook
    Left = 256
    Top = 192
    ResourcesBin = {
      464D585F5354594C4520322E3501060D74657374626C75727374796C65034401
      060F74657374736861646F777374796C65039301060D74657374676C6F777374
      796C65036A010611746573746E6F6566666563747374796C65030A0100545046
      3007544C61796F757400095374796C654E616D65060D74657374626C75727374
      796C6505416C69676E0706436C69656E740A53697A652E576964746805000000
      00000040F108400B53697A652E48656967687405000000000000008A08401453
      697A652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C74080756697369626C6508085461
      624F726465720200000A5452656374616E676C6500095374796C654E616D6506
      0E72656374616E676C657374796C6505416C69676E0706436C69656E740A5369
      7A652E57696474680500000000000040F108400B53697A652E48656967687405
      000000000000008A08401453697A652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C7408
      00000B54426C757245666665637400095374796C654E616D65060F626C757265
      66666563747374796C6508536F66746E6573730500000000009A9999FD3F0000
      005450463007544C61796F757400095374796C654E616D65060F746573747368
      61646F777374796C6505416C69676E0706436C69656E740A53697A652E576964
      74680500000000000000C804400B53697A652E48656967687405000000000000
      00C804401453697A652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C7408085461624F72
      6465720201000A5452656374616E676C6500095374796C654E616D65060E7265
      6374616E676C657374796C6505416C69676E0706436C69656E740A53697A652E
      57696474680500000000000000C804400B53697A652E48656967687405000000
      00000000C804401453697A652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C740800000D
      54536861646F7745666665637400095374796C654E616D650611736861646F77
      6566666563747374796C650844697374616E63650500000000000000C0004009
      446972656374696F6E0500000000000000B4044008536F66746E657373050000
      0000009A9999FD3F074F7061636974790500000000009A9999FE3F0B53686164
      6F77436F6C6F720708636C61426C61636B0000005450463007544C61796F7574
      00095374796C654E616D65060D74657374676C6F777374796C6505416C69676E
      0706436C69656E740A53697A652E57696474680500000000000040F108400B53
      697A652E48656967687405000000000000008A08401453697A652E506C617466
      6F726D44656661756C74080756697369626C6508085461624F72646572020200
      0A5452656374616E676C6500095374796C654E616D65060E72656374616E676C
      657374796C6505416C69676E0706436C69656E740A53697A652E576964746805
      00000000000040F108400B53697A652E48656967687405000000000000008A08
      401453697A652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C740800000B54476C6F7745
      666665637400095374796C654E616D65060F676C6F776566666563747374796C
      6508536F66746E657373050000000000CDCCCCFD3F09476C6F77436F6C6F7207
      07636C61476F6C64074F7061636974790500000000006666E6FE3F0000005450
      463007544C61796F757400095374796C654E616D650611746573746E6F656666
      6563747374796C6505416C69676E0706436C69656E740A53697A652E57696474
      680500000000000040F108400B53697A652E4865696768740500000000000000
      8A08401453697A652E506C6174666F726D44656661756C74080756697369626C
      6508085461624F726465720203000A5452656374616E676C6500095374796C65
      4E616D65060E72656374616E676C657374796C6505416C69676E0706436C6965
      6E740A53697A652E57696474680500000000000040F108400B53697A652E4865
      6967687405000000000000008A08401453697A652E506C6174666F726D446566
      61756C7408000000}
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 136.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 161.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 5
    Text = 'Assign StyleBook to Form'
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 192.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 161.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 3
    Text = 'Assign Style to Panel'
    OnClick = Button2Click
  end
  object Button3: TButton
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 248.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 161.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 1
    Text = 'Clear Style Book and Style'
    OnClick = Button3Click
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Align = Right
    Position.X = 248.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 392.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 480.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 4
  end
  object ComboBox1: TComboBox
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 56.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 161.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 6
  end
  object Label1: TLabel
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 40.000000000000000000
    Text = 'Style'
  end
  object BlurEffect1: TBlurEffect
    Softness = 0.300000011920929000
  end
end
```

Comment: What GPU does your server have? Does the crash occur at console or in a RDP session?

Comment: If it is an ATI ES1000, then you are out of luck, no shader support...

Comment: @whosrdaddy So they do have the ATI ES1000... This is unfortunate. Is there any way to detect shader support at runtime?

Comment: sure, but that would be a new question :)

Comment: Going to close this question as a dupe.