# Detect if GPU supports Pixel Shader 2.0 at runtime (Firemonkey)

Tags: delphi, directx, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

This question comes from my previous question here:

[Delphi XE7 Abstract Error on StyleLookup with Effect (FireMonkey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968813/delphi-xe7-abstract-error-on-stylelookup-with-effect-firemonkey?noredirect=1#comment46194475_28968813)

Basically, I have several styled controls with effects applied. The effects work on most systems so I don't want to take them out of my styles all together for the select few customers they won't work on. Is there a way to detect whether or not the client has DirectX 9 **AND** the GPU installed supports Pixel Shader 2.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK there is not a direct way to determine the DirectX version, however  Microsoft provides a sample function called *GetDXVersion* which is part of the DirectX SDK. This function runs a set of checks to determine the DirectX version. Luckily you can found a Delphi translation of that function in the [`DSPack`](https://code.google.com/p/dspack/source/browse/trunk/src/DSPack/DXSUtil.pas#3692) project.

Now to detect the pixel shader version you must use the [`IDirect3D9::GetDeviceCaps`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method and then check the value of the `PixelShaderVersion` field of the [`D3DCAPS9`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) record.

Try this FMX sample

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Direct3D9,
  FMX.Context.DX9;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    LCaps: TD3DCaps9;
    LPixelShaderVersionMajor, LPixelShaderVersionMinor : Cardinal;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@LCaps, SizeOf(LCaps));
  if TCustomDX9Context.Direct3D9Obj.GetDeviceCaps(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, LCaps) = S_OK then
  begin
    LPixelShaderVersionMajor:= D3DSHADER_VERSION_MAJOR(LCaps.PixelShaderVersion);
    LPixelShaderVersionMinor:= D3DSHADER_VERSION_MINOR(LCaps.PixelShaderVersion);
    ShowMessage(Format('PixelShaderVersion %d.%d', [LPixelShaderVersionMajor, LPixelShaderVersionMinor]));
  end;

   //also you can use the D3DPS_VERSION function to determine if the version returned meets the requirements
  if (LCaps.PixelShaderVersion >= D3DPS_VERSION(2, 0)) then
   ShowMessage('Hey your PixelShaderVersion is compatible');
end;
```

Comment: Really appreciate it!

Comment: To expand on this answer, there is the `TCustomDX9Context.HardwareSupported` boolean function, but it only checks if it can initialize DirectX9, Embarcadero should include the shader version check in this function...